# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision' has no attribute 'set_global_policy'

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, google-colaboratory

I need to add [mixed precision](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/mixed_precision) to my code in order to save some memory. Specifically, I have tried adding mixed precision policy near line 27 in https://github.com/nimRobotics/google-research/blob/master/ravens/train.py, below is the code excerpt

```
import argparse
import datetime
import os

import numpy as np
from ravens import agents
from ravens import Dataset
import tensorflow as tf

# tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy('mixed_float16')

# OR

# policy = tf.keras.mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16')
# mixed_precision.set_global_policy(policy)
```

Both the methods result in attribute error as shown below, I'm using Google Colab with TF 2.3.0

Using `tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy('mixed_float16')` results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 28, in <module>
    tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy('mixed_float16')
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision' has no attribute 'set_global_policy'
```

Using

```
policy = tf.keras.mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16')
mixed_precision.set_global_policy(policy)
```

results in

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 29, in <module>
    policy = tf.keras.mixed_precision.Policy('mixed_float16')
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.keras.mixed_precision' has no attribute 'Policy'
```

Any help or hints will be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For `tf < 2.4` you should use [mixed precision](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/mixed_precision/experimental/Policy)'s experimental package.

```
tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.Policy(
    name, loss_scale='auto'
)
```

For ex, in `tf 2.3`

```
policy = tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.Policy('mixed_float16')
tf.keras.mixed_precision.experimental.set_policy(policy)
```

and in `tf 2.4`

```
tf.keras.mixed_precision.set_global_policy('mixed_float16')
```

From `tf 2.4`, this feature is no longer experimental.

Comment: Could this be linked somehow with the issue?

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/mixed_precision/experimental/LossScaleOptimizer

Warning: The experimental class is deprecated and will be removed in TensorFlow 2.5. Please use the non-experimental class tf.keras.mixed_precision.LossScaleOptimizer instead.

Comment: The link you provided is broken. And also what's the issue you faced?